# How to upload php file on local host and access it from frontend site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, localhost

I don't have clue that this type of question is allowed on this site or not but please give me guidance. I'm facing problem with my project.
Currently I am learning backend web development.
By completing all beginnings of php I want to apply this practically.
So now I am doing my project named "Image Resizer". I have successfully completed php coding that resize the image but the problem I'm facing is: I didn't have domain and hosting services. So now I decided to work on local host. I have all the frontend html,css,javascript code but i don't know how to implement it on local host and please guide me how to implement php code with local host that upload the image on my local host for testing my website.
For example:

```
<form action"?"></form>
```

what will be my local host domain in action"?"
And How to upload my php file on local host and how to access it from my frontend site?

Comment: Yeah, definitely off topic here. You need a web server running and PHP installed on your local computer (e.g. Apache, Nginx, IIS) and then once that's up and running you would point your browser to `http://localhost`.

Comment: yes I need a web server on my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you will be needing software like xampp(https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and wamp(http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (which are the famous servers for local hosting ).

Then install one of them and run the mysql and apache , after that make your php file to be executed well you could either use the form method to link your site to other php file or you could also right the php inside according to what you want to do, you can google it, in case if you can't wait until you google it inside action you will put the php file where you put your commands and you will use an attribute called method  either the  get method  or the post method to tell it what kind of operation it is going to do in the opened php file (`<form action".php" method='get/post'></form>`) . and make sure the extension of your webpage is .php then if you are using wamp go to the place where you installed it and find the directory 'www' then put any folder name where you would put your php file in it, if you are using xampp do the same process for a folder called httdocs. then run your favorite browser and type localhost:/[your php file with out the square bracket or the directory you created/your file, you need to remember you always should have at least one directory inside 'www' if you are using wamp but  if you are using xampp it is fine to just save the .php file inside httdocs ],  for inserting a data like  images and others you need to know mysql (data base management systems) or sql (relational database management systems) or others so google about them. This is just the tip of the ice burg, i hope it will help.

Comment: I am using wamp server. Is i save my php file into www directory then what should i do after it?

Comment: First creat a directory in www then save your php inside. Then go to your browser I would suggest chrome then type localhost in the search bar. Then at the bottom of the page you would see some thing that says your projects in there you would get the folder you created  click on it, then it shall display the php files you saved inside there, don't forget to start your wamp server.